# Как сохранять все ошибки Exception?

Tags: php, ооп, исключения

Создал метод, который сохраняет ошибки полученные от try catch в файл,
но проблема в том, что ошибки сохраняются по одной, то есть если при загрузке страницы возникнет 5 ошибок, то в файл запишется первая ошибка. И пока её не исправишь, то вторая не запишется.
Как сделать, что бы все ошибки сохранялись сразу?
Вот мой метод:

```
# Записываем ошибки в файл
function Error($errors){
    $file = ROOT . "admin/tmp/errors.txt";
    if(file_exists($file)){ // если файл существует
        if(filesize($file) > 5242880){ // если файл больше N кб (5 Мб)
            $fp = fopen($file, "w");
            flock($file, LOCK_EX);
            fwrite($fp, $errors . " | " . date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time()) . "\r\n");
            flock($file, LOCK_UN);
        }
    }
    $fp = fopen($file, "a");
    fwrite($fp, $errors . " | " . date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time()) . "\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Вывзванное исключение "поднимается" вверх пока не будет перехвачено первым попавшимся на пути catch. Вам необходимо ловить каждый Exeception в момент его вызова. Далее, в блоке catch производить логирование: catch (Exception $e) { Log::error($e->getMessage()); } Собственно, в ответе @Razzwan это указано. Предлагаю использовать для логирования [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) или иное решение, а не собственный "велосипед". В будущем для ротации логов используйте стандартную linux-утилиту [logrotate](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=logrotate).

Answer (score 1):

НЕ НУЖНО создавать таких методов.

В нормальном приложении может быть только две ситуации:

1. Произошло что-то действительно исключительное, из ряда вон выходящее. В этом случае надо не продолжать работу и записывать другие проблемы (которые в 99% случаев являются просто следствием самой первой проблемы), а просто аварийно завершить работу скрипта.
2. Произошло обрабатываемое исключение. В этом случае его надо перехватить, обработать, и продолжать дальше. Логировать можно по желанию, но смысла в этом немного - если исключение является штатным, то в обычном режиме никто не логирует штатные операции.

Не нужно заниматься логированием. Никогда не нужно ловить ошибку только для того чтобы её залогировать. Не нужно изобретать велосипедов. **РНР прекрасно справляется с логированием сам.**

Comment: В принципе Вы правы, спасибо. Но вопрос был не в том, что и как я должен делать, а именно как решить мою задачу. Это уже десятое дело, делать мне это или не делать. Спасибо за совет, мне он понравился.